# How to count from first date till date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below in SQL server

| Date | Store ID | Sales Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 1001 | 1000$ |
| 01-01-2021 | 1002 | 1000$ |
| 01-01-2021 | 1003 | 0$ |
| 02-01-2021 | 1001 | 1000$ |
| 02-01-2021 | 1002 | 1000$ |
| 02-01-2021 | 1003 | 1000$ |
| 03-01-2021 | 1001 | 1000$ |
| 03-01-2021 | 1002 | 1000$ |
| 03-01-2021 | 1003 | 1000$ |

how to calculate count of previous days if Sales Amount > 0, using TSQL? (same as below column)

| Date | Store ID | Sales Amount | Active Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 1001 | 1000$ | 1 |
| 01-01-2021 | 1002 | 1000$ | 1 |
| 01-01-2021 | 1003 | 0$ | 0 |
| 02-01-2021 | 1001 | 1000$ | 2 |
| 02-01-2021 | 1002 | 1000$ | 2 |
| 02-01-2021 | 1003 | 1000$ | 1 |
| 03-01-2021 | 1001 | 1000$ | 3 |
| 03-01-2021 | 1002 | 1000$ | 3 |
| 03-01-2021 | 1003 | 1000$ | 2 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using [[tag:mysql]] doesn't use [[tag:tsql]] (that's SQL Server/Sybase's SQL Dialect). What have **you** tried solve the problem? *Why* didn't your attempts work?

Comment: Your question makes very little sense. How are you calculating the new column, there seems to be no logic to the numbers you have placed in the example

Comment: Also if you can write a query to get that data, then dont add a column to the table, consider writing a View instead, then the numbers will be correct always

Comment: If you're using SQL Server *why* did you tag [[tag:mysql]] *and* [[tag:tsql]] again when I just explained they conflict ...?

Comment: Please, for the 3rd time, stop tag spamming...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unclear what product(s) the OP is using. They state SQL Server in their question, but have readded the tag [[tag:mysql]] back to the question 3 times with no additional explanation as to why their question is about both products. This makes the question unclear and confusing as we don't know what RDBMS they are *really* using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

… conditional window aggregate …

(as you’ve mentioned you are using sql server)

```
sum(case when SalesAmount > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by StoreId order by Date) as ActiveDays
```